# Commission free trades for non permanent resident?

Tags: united-states, online-brokerage, commission

My brokerage gives me a few commission free trades per month. Non-citizen, non-permanent residents cannot open an account. Are there any brokerages that offer commission-free trades and are open to people that don't have a green card?

Comment: Non-citizen, non-resident... **Where**? I'm guessing the US, since you mentioned green card? And which brokerage is it?

Comment: Yes United States.  Sorry about that.

Comment: This question seems to be asking for a product recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, US banks/brokerages treat US **tax** residents the same as they treat US citizens/permanent residents, for deposit/investment accounts purposes. You may be not a permanent resident (green card holder), but you may definitely open accounts as resident if you're a *tax* resident.

Usually, the distinction is in the form of your identification: as a non-resident you use form W8-BEN, as a resident (even if you don't have a green card, but are in H1B or L1 status, for example) you use W9. That is all they generally care about.

I have yet to see a bank that doesn't open accounts to non-citizens and non-permanent residents, but I have seen banks that do not open accounts to non-residents for tax purposes. I think that is the source of your confusion.

Comment: From what I can tell, Merrill Lynch does not allow non-permanent residents to open an investment account. I just called them and asked.

Comment: Also can't open an account with Fidelity or Charles Schwab.

Comment: The person attempting to open the account has an H1B.

Comment: What about E*Trade and such?